# bounded degree graph colouring.

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, discrete-mathematics

I was wondering if anyone could provide references on the following:

1. Is determining the chromatic number of a bounded degree graph APX-complete?

2.I've seen the result that states it is NP-hard to decided whether a $4$ bounded graph is $3$ colourable. In general for a $d$ bounded degree graph which positive integers $k$ is it NP-hard to determine whether the graph is $k$-colourable?

Comment: You can artificially increase the degree by adding a bipartite star graph.

Comment: Could you elaborate slightly? Are you saying for a fixed bounded degree $d$ we can prove hardness for all $k \leq d$ by making some sort of reduction which adds a bipartite star graph? If so where is the starting point of hardness $k=3$?

Comment: The starting point for $k=3$ is $d=4$ -- the line graph of 3-regular graph for which edge coloring is NP-hard. To get $d=5$ add new vertex and an edge to any of the vertices, this doesn't change the chromatic number.

Comment: yes i see this, how can we increase $k$ though? Maybe add a clique instead?